# 'all images for the production variant AllTraffic exist, the execution role used to create the model has permissions to access them'

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker, tensorflow-serving, aws-policies

I saw this link: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/912, it's similar to my question but not the same, my error is:

```
Please make sure all images included in the model for the production variant AllTraffic exist, and that the execution role used to create the model has permissions to access them.
```

Because of the security setting of my AWS account, I can't attach SageMaker fullaccess to the execution role, but I did add :

```
{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",                
                "ecr:BatchDeleteImage",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:DeleteRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:DeleteRepository",
                "ecr:PutImage"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ecr:*:*:repository/*sagemaker*"
        },
```

in the policies and attached to this execution role, I'm new to SageMaker, does anyone know why I got this error?

Here's some of the codes:

```
from sagemaker.tensorflow.serving import Model

model = Model(model_data=model_data,
              role=role,
              framework_version='1.15.2',
              sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
              name=name)

predictor = model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1,
    instance_type='ml.m4.2xlarge',
    endpoint_name=name,
    update_endpoint=False)
```